# clickhouse server error - filesystem error

Tags: clickhouse

```bash
[root@localhost /]# sudo tail -n 10 /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log


9. ? @ 0x154cb2dc in /usr/bin/clickhouse
10. ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<ThreadFromGlobalPool, void*>) @ 0xaf6546a in /usr/bin/clickhouse
11. ThreadFromGlobalPool::ThreadFromGlobalPool<void ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::scheduleImpl<void>(std::__1::function<void ()>, int, std::__1::optional<unsigned long>)::'lambda0'()>(void&&, void ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::scheduleImpl<void>(std::__1::function<void ()>, int, std::__1::optional<unsigned long>)::'lambda0'()&&...)::'lambda'()::operator()() @ 0xaf674a4 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
12. ThreadPoolImpl<std::__1::thread>::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<std::__1::thread, void*>) @ 0xaf62837 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
13. ? @ 0xaf662fd in /usr/bin/clickhouse
14. start_thread @ 0x7ea5 in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
15. __clone @ 0xfeb0d in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so

Cannot print extra info for Poco::Exception (version 22.2.2.1)
2022.08.30 17:34:13.036190 [ 11926 ] {} <Error> Application: filesystem error: in directory_iterator::directory_iterator(...): No such file or directory [/var/lib/clickhouse/store/848/848085d9-4c3c-4a59-9c5b-6481f8022781/202208_215813_215813_0/data.mrk3]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you did before hitting this error? Also, please share your cluster setup as well.

Answer (score -1):

You need to upgrade CH to 22.3.12.19